# Sound issues with RaspberryPi 2 and OSMC (Kodi)

Tags: audio, video, raspberry-pi2, kodi

I have sound issues with some video files I want to play from an external HDD with my Raspberry Pi 2 and OSMC. Instead of the video sound I hear a very loud chattering, rusteling sound. Kind of like a machine gun sound in an old video game. The Error only occurs with certain video files, the others work fine. 
As audio output, I use HDMI as the Raspberry is connected to my projector. This is then connected to my speakers.

As I thought it might be a codec problem, I allready bought and activated MPEG-II and VC1 codecs, but this did not help.

Here some information on one of the malfunctioning files:

```
General
Complete name                            : hds-hp1-rmx.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 2
File size                                : 24.1 GiB
Duration                                 : 2h 38mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 21.7 Mbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2011-04-16 09:29:16
Writing application                      : mkvmerge v4.6.0 ('Still Crazy After All These Years') gebaut am Mar 10 2011 02:50:32
Writing library                          : libebml v1.2.0 + libmatroska v1.1.0

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : VC-1
Format profile                           : Advanced@L3
Codec ID                                 : V_MS/VFW/FOURCC / WVC1
Codec ID/Hint                            : Microsoft
Duration                                 : 2h 38mn
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Default                                  : No
Forced                                   : No

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : A_AC3
Duration                                 : 2h 38mn
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 448 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 509 MiB (2%)
Language                                 : German
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : Yes

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : DTS
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Format profile                           : MA / Core
Mode                                     : 16
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : A_DTS
Duration                                 : 2h 38mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : Unknown / 1 509 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossless / Lossy
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : No
Forced                                   : No
```

I have the same problem with files with the following codecs:
V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC (Video) & A_AC3 (Audio)

But V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC (Video) & A_DTS (Audio) work fine...
I am thankful for any hint.

Kind regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 1):

Alright,

after hours of Google Search and even some scripting I found the solution.
As often, it was unbelievably simple...

The problem, in my case, was, that my projector simply does not support AC3. So I only had to deactivate the AC3 Audio passthrough in the Kodi Settings and now it works like a charm.

I hope this also helps someone else, than only me. This is why I will keep this monologue of mine online.